# After rendering a Jinja2 template, can I get the set values?

Tags: jinja2

I want to render a Jinja2 template, and after the rendering, read the values that were set by it:

```py
import jinja2

template = jinja2.Template("""
    {% set number = 42 %}
    Hello {{name}} {{number}}!
    """)

vars = {"name": "Ned"}
print(template.render(vars).strip())
print(vars)
```

This prints:

```
Hello Ned 42!
{'name': 'Ned'}
```

Is there something I can do after `template.render` that would give me the value of `number`?  Also, I need to do it without knowing the name `number` beforehand.  I want to discover whatever values have been set in the template.

Comment: How do you not know the variable's name of 'number' in a controlled template?  A rendered template is just a string,  so you could regex that value out of it.

Comment: The templates are authored by others, I'm writing some tooling to pull a number of templates together into a cohesive document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it without using functions that are documented, but say not to use them:

```
import jinja2

template = jinja2.Template("""
    {% set number = 52 %}
    {% set choice = "apple" %}
    Hello {{name}} {{number}}!
    {% if number > 50 %}
        More than 40!
        {% set also = 'foo' %}
    {% endif %}
    """)

ctx = template.new_context(vars = {"name": "Ned"})
template.render(ctx)
mod = template.module
template_vars = {n:getattr(mod, n) for n in dir(mod) if not n.startswith("_")}
print(template_vars)
```

This prints:

```
{'also': 'foo', 'choice': 'apple', 'number': 52}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, this is a kinda hack but it seems you can do something with `Context` from `jinja2.runtime` like

```py
$ cat show_vars.py
import jinja2

template = jinja2.Template("""
    {% set number = 42 %}
    Hello {{name}} {{number}}!
    """)

vars = {"name": "Ned"}
print(template.render(vars).strip())
print(vars)

from jinja2 import Environment
from jinja2.runtime import Context

env = Environment()

ctx = Context(env, vars, '', template.blocks)
list(template.root_render_func(ctx))
print(ctx.vars)
print(ctx.get_all())

$ python show_vars.py
Hello Ned 42!
{'name': 'Ned'}
{'number': 42}
{'name': 'Ned', 'number': 42}
```

As @[nedbat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14343/ned-batchelder) pointed out, one can also achieve the same with

```py
import jinja2

template = jinja2.Template("""
    {% set number = 42 %}
    Hello {{name}} {{number}}!
    {% if number > 50 %}
        More than 40!
        {% set also = 'foo' %}
    {% endif %}
    """)

ctx = template.new_context(vars = {"name": "Ned"})
list(template.root_render_func(ctx))
print("get_all:", ctx.get_all())
print("exported_vars:", ctx.exported_vars)
print("vars:", ctx.vars)
```

Comment: This works, but the [docs for root_render_func](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#jinja2.Template.root_render_func) say, "this function should only be called from within a render() / generate() / stream() call," so I'm not sure I want to use it... :(

Comment: @NedBatchelder yeah, I felt like this was a hack too. But I wonder, why they made it a public api though. Also for sync call, it's more or less the same, except the error handling in `Template.render` which is `try:  list(self.root_render_func(ctx)) except Exception: environment.handle_exception()`

Answer (score 0):

With the context provided:

```py
import jinja2
import re

template = jinja2.Template("""
    {% set number = 42 %}
    Hello {{name}} {{number}}!
    """)

vars = {"name": "Ned"}
rendered = template.render(vars).strip()
print(vars)
print(rendered)
changed_var_value = re.findall(r'Hello[\s\S]*\s{1}(.*)!', rendered)
print(f'var after the greeting: {changed_var_value}')
```

output:

```
{'name': 'Ned'}
Hello Ned 42!
var after the greeting: ['42']
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't assume I know anything at all about the template.  I want to be able to render an arbitrary template, and then examine its locals after the fact.